# Replace specific commas in a JSON stored in a column

Tags: json, sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have SQL Sever 2016. One of the columns in my DB tables holds JSON data that looks something like this (of special interest is the comma-separated list of numbers):

```
[{"problemTypeID":"11,16,21,12,13,15,17,19,14,18,26,20,25,27,28,24","field":"problemTypeID","fromSidePanel":true,"operator":"eq","value":"11,16,21,12,13,15,17,19,14,18,26,20,25,27,28,24"}]
```

I want to replace all the commas only inside the sections that have the comma-separated list of numbers, with double 'OR' symbols. That is, I want this to become something like:

```
[{"problemTypeID":"11||16||21||12||13||15||17||19||14||18||26||20||25||27||28||24","field":"problemTypeID","fromSidePanel":true,"operator":"eq","value":"11||16||21||12||13||15||17||19||14||18||26||20||25||27||28||24"}]
```

How do I do this on my SQL server? Are there T-SQL options or will I be forced to use CLR?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know, json has quite good support for arrays. Why do this weird pipe thing when you can use proper field type? It's like storing csv in xml attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use a couple of nested `JSON_MODIFY` functions. As your data is also in an array wrapper, you need to reference that with the `[0]`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (YourJSON nvarchar(MAX));

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (YourJSON)
VALUES(N'[{"problemTypeID":"11,16,21,12,13,15,17,19,14,18,26,20,25,27,28,24","field":"problemTypeID","fromSidePanel":true,"operator":"eq","value":"11,16,21,12,13,15,17,19,14,18,26,20,25,27,28,24"}]');
GO

UPDATE YT
SET YT.YourJSON = JSON_MODIFY(JSON_MODIFY(YT.YourJSON,'$[0].problemTypeID',REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(YT.YourJSON,'$[0].problemTypeID'),',','||')),'$.value',REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(YT.YourJSON,'$[0].value'),',','||'))
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```